# Geometric picture of attaching a 2-cell to the 2-torus

Tags: algebraic-topology

Im currently reading about attaching spaces and I was wondering what is the geometric picture of attaching a 2-cell to the 2-torus via the map $f: S^1 \xrightarrow{(1,0)} S^1 \times S^1$.

For me it seems like geometrically I have filled a 1-dimensional hole, making $H_1((T^2)_f)= \mathbb{Z}$.

Is this a well-known space? What happens now with $H_2((T^2)_f)$?

For $S^2$ I have somehow obtained an idea of $S^2$ being some sort of a higher dimensional loop. Is this sound? Is there a corresponding picture for $T^2$ and $(T^2)_f$?

I am mostly wondering about the geometric interpretation.

I have very basic knowledge in algebraic topology.

Comment: Well, you have essentially glued a disk along the meridian of the torus. Now you can slide the bits of the torus along the disk to see that it's homotopy equivalent to $S^2$ with two poles identified. This is in turn homotopy equivalent to $S^2 \vee S^1$. So $H_2 \cong \Bbb Z$, and indeed $H_1 \cong \Bbb Z$.

Comment: I managed to resolve the specific problem. I had not thought about it being the wedge product as you mention, but now that you mention it, I have a geometric picture of why that is true.